# Feasability of having another process write to the mongo database used in a Meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I've got an application where I'm populating a Mongo database. That code is not super easily portable to Meteor, so that I'm doing is running that code in a separate process and writing data to Mongo collections.

In my Meteor application, I point it at that shared Mongo instead of the default instance. The application works reasonably well, but the updates don't seem to happen as fast as I would have expected. When I write a value to Mongo from my external process, it seems to take a while before my client refreshes to show updated content. There is about 7MB of total data in my Mongo database.

Is this approach to share a Mongo and write to it from an external process feasible or is it not advised?

Thanks!

Eric.

Answer (score 2):

As MongoDB doesn't have any live-queries Meteor polls for changes it missed every 10 seconds. Therefore it can take up to 10 seconds until changes  are noticed by Meteor.

About the approach in general: it is fine to do so. If you need faster updates you might need to use an other approach or trigger Meteor to update itself (not sure if this is possible at all). Also note that meteor might not support every MongoDB feature yet.

**Further readings**

- [Multi-Server architecture and concurrency](https://trello.com/card/multitier-server-architecture-support-very-large-numbers-of-simultaneous-clients/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/46)
- [Talk at the Dev-Workshop: How Meteor is Scaling Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/02/06/meteor-devshop-0-share-knowledge-not-germs)

Comment: Uh, Meteor polls? How scalable is this?

Comment: @Mitar: As far as I know there are apps with up to 500 concurrent users. But scaling is WIP. There are plans to improve this (see links in updated answer)